# Designing a transparent header bar that text cannot be seen through

Tags: javascript, css

I am using CSS and React to design a mobile site.  The background of my homepage is a picture spanning the full width and height of the screen.  I want to have a transparent header, so users can see the picture through the header.  However, I don't want the text to show through the header when the user scrolls.

My project structure is:

```
<App>
  <Header />
  <Body />
</App>
```

The current header styling is:

```
.mobileHeader {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

and the body styling:

```
    background-image: url(${homePicture});
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
```

I some text on my body component but when I scroll up that text is visible through the header.  I would like the background image to remain visible through the header, but not text.

Comment: In other words: You want the text to be transparent (only) when it's behind the header. I don't think this is possible. To some extent probably a rather complex javascript sensing the scroll position could do a part of it, but you certainly can't make half a text line transparent when it's (vertically) half behind the header (not even half a paragraph, I suppose)

Comment: Yes, basically I want a div that blocks all content underneath except for the background image.

Comment: Could you get the effect you’re looking for by attaching the homePicture to the header as a background with the same styling (fixed, no repeat). It would cause the text on the page to abruptly disappear as the user scrolled, but the text would not be seen under the header. If you want the text to fade as it’s scrolled and if your header is always the same height, you could make a copy the background image using your graphics editor, size the height to your header height, and then add a gradient to the alpha channel for the bottom edge of the image.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [scroll event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/scroll_event) to detect if window is being scrolled. Then add transparency and delayed transitions to your text to hide/show the text.

Comment: The text should always be visible as long as it is not underneath the header.

Comment: Ahh. I got it. Not sure it is possible.   
Have you any live examples?